# Textpattern search with printout of line

Tags: powershell, full-text-search, text-search

I'm an Network Engineer an I wrote a small but effective PS Script to search logs(or any file for that matter) for textpatterns. Now this script only outputs the line, filename and so on. Now I wanted to extend the script so that when it finds a line, it'll tell me the line, filename and so on but also the contents of that line.

So it should look like this:

```
LineNumber Filename            Path                           Pattern                                  
---------- --------            ----                           -------                                  
4          190719_Success.log  C:\skripte\190719_Success.log  test
```

*Text that's on Line 4 of the .log should appear here*

```
5          190719_Success.log  C:\skripte\190719_Success.log  test
```

*Text thats on Line 5 of the .log should appear here*

Sorry for the formatting, I hope you get what I mean.

Since I'm relatively new to PS Scripting Im kinda lost how I should achieve this goal or if thats even possible.

Here is my code sofar:

```
Clear-Host
$Pfad = Read-Host "Bitte Pfad angeben" #Enter Directory Path to Search
$Suchbegriff = Read-Host "Suchbegriff eingeben" #Enter Pattern to search for
New-Item -ItemType directory -Path C:\Skripte -erroraction 'silentlycontinue' #create C:\Skripte Folder
Remove-Item -Path C:\Skripte\Suchergebnis.txt -erroraction 'silentlycontinue' #Cleanup from previous run
Remove-Item -Path C:\Skripte\Indizierung.csv -erroraction 'silentlycontinue' #Cleanup
cd $Pfad 

echo $file.fullname
echo ""
select-string -Path .\*.* -Pattern "$Suchbegriff" -erroraction 'silentlycontinue' | Select-Object LineNumber,Filename,Path,Pattern | ft -wrap #Search the specified Directory
echo ""

while(($Create = Read-Host -Prompt "Unterordner durchsuchen? J für Ja, N für Nein") -ne "x") #Userinput if Subdirectorys should be searched aswell
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     {
 switch ($Create)

{
        'J' 
{
Get-Childitem  -erroraction 'silentlycontinue' | Get-ChildItem -Recurse -erroraction 'silentlycontinue' | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer} | Export-CSV -NoClobber -NoTypeInformation -Path C:\Skripte\Indizierung.csv #Get all Subdirectorys and put them in a CSV, two GCI are needed to reliably get all subdirectories.
$Files = import-csv -Delimiter ',' -Path C:\Skripte\Indizierung.csv #Import CSV
foreach ($File in $Files)
{
cd $file.fullname
echo $file.fullname
echo ""
select-string -Path .\*.* -Pattern "$Suchbegriff" -erroraction 'silentlycontinue' | Select-Object LineNumber,Filename,Path,Pattern | ft -wrap
echo ""
pause
exit
} 
}
        'n'
{
pause
Exit
}       
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the following code. I added a loop for processing the files and some validation for the input + your request for the displaying the line content to the console.

**Code adapted (@Theo: thanks for input)**

```
#Get input
[System.String]$SearchPath = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter path'
[System.String]$SearchPattern = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter search pattern'
[System.String]$SearchRecurse = Read-Host -Prompt 'Search recurse (Y/N)'

#Validate input
if ((-not $SearchPath) -or (-not (Test-Path -Path $SearchPath)))
{
    throw ('Path "' + $SearchPath + 'is not available!')
}

if ((-not $SearchPattern))
{
    throw ('Search pattern is empty!')
}

if (('Y', 'N') -notcontains $SearchRecurse)
{
    throw ('Search recurse parameter "' + $SearchRecurse + ' is not valid!')
}

#Get all files
Out-Host -InputObject 'Get all files...'
[PSCustomObject[]]$Files = @()
if ($SearchRecurse -eq 'Y')
{
    $Files = Get-ChildItem -Path $SearchPath -File -Recurse -Force #Collect also files from subfolders
}
else
{
    $Files = Get-ChildItem -Path $SearchPath -File -Force #Collect only files from the current folder
}

#Search for string
Out-Host -InputObject 'Search for string...'
[PSCustomObject[]]$Output = @()
foreach ($File in ($Files)) #Process each file
{
    Out-Host -InputObject $File.FullName
    $Output += Select-String -Path $File.FullName -Pattern $SearchPattern | Select-Object -Property LineNumber, Filename, Path, Pattern, Line
}

$Output | Format-Table -Wrap
```

Comment: You sir are amazing. I have tried it and it it works good so far, but is it possible to check the files immediatly instead of collecting them first? If I want to search exchange logs for specific texts, it'll probably take days to run, since there are ~80.000 logs on the exchange I tested this on.

Comment: You could replace the `foreach ($File in $Files)` with a `Get-ChildItem | Foreach-Object -Process {}` loop. So the files will be processed directly. Please try to modify my script and if you need any help let us know.

Comment: `Select-String` has a `-Path` parameter, so you don't need to use `Get-Content` first. Also, I would `[regex]::Escape()` the searchpattern before use, especially since a user can type in anything and that anything may well contain regex special characters

Comment: @Theo: Is there a way to get the content of the matching line when you use directly the `-Path` parameter?

Comment: Thank you both, I'll try to modify it myself and play around, i'll let you know if I have more questions or when I have a new draft.

Comment: @Patrick sure, just try `Select-String -Path D:\bla.txt -Pattern $searchPattern | fl *`, you'll find properties like LineNumber, Line (the line in which the search pattern was found, etc.

Comment: @Theo: thanks, i've totally overseen these :-) I changed the example code.